# Shutting down producers/consumers in spring-integration with poison pill

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, message-queue, producer-consumer

How would one utilize poison pill to stop message handlers (and message suppliers) with spring-integration?

I have a setup of N producers (subclassed Supplier) and M consumers (subclasses GenericHandler). They are connected via unbounded queue.

Producers should send K messages each, then send poison pill (I think each producer should send M/N poison pills, that is).

I would like then, to stop producers altogether (they are controlled by TaskExecutor)

```
@Bean(name = "supplierExecutor")
Executor supplierExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    executor.setCorePoolSize(x);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(y);
    executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(0);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(z);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("supplier-");

    executor.initialize();

    return executor;
}
```

Also, I would like to stop consumers altogether, but gracefully. (They are controlled by their own TaskScheduler)

```
@Bean(name = "consumerScheduler")
TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

    taskScheduler.setPoolSize(a);
    taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("temp-consumer");
    taskScheduler.initialize();
    taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);

    return taskScheduler;
}
```

Right now, in my supplier `get()` method, I have the following snippet

```
public Foo get() {
    if (reachedMaxSendLimit()) {
        incrementMsgSentCount();
        return POISON_PILL;
    } else if (surpassedMaxSentLimit()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return handlePayload(payload);
    }
}
```

Is there a well-defined way to achieve the behaviour I'm trying to accomplish?
I am aware how I'd do it without spring with regular Runnables, but I'm a bit clueless here.

Comment: Why not put your logic in the queue between producers and consumers? If your queue has seen N ProducerFinished messages, it puts M EndOfQueue messages at the end of the queue

Comment: @PaulJanssens I'm afraid I'm not sure how I should put that logic in spring's message channel. Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `poison pill` and it's not clear to me what you are talking about here, but if the story is about `stop`, then you definitely should consider existing `org.springframework.context.Lifecycle` control in Spring. In this case all the Spring Integration endpoints are of that type and you simply can use their `stop()`.

For the management purposes Spring Integration provides [Control Bus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus) component. For that you can send a command message with the `stop()` expression to really stop particular endpoint.

Note: it's good practice to stop producers before consumers. This way you won't lose messages for which there is no already consumers to process.

Comment: "Poison pill" is a pattern (I guess you could call it that), which describes a situation where a producer tells a consumer there are no more messages to process from now on.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't sound for me as reasonable behavior. If there is no more messages, the consumer is just in idle state: nothing to consumer - nothing to do! What am I missing? Maybe there is more information somehwere on the matter and we would introduce such a pattern into the Spring Integration per se ?

Comment: Here it is: http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/22-queues/ just scroll down to poison pill

Comment: Cool! Would really mind to raise a JIRA in Spring Integration for future consideration? Meanwhile I suggest you to take a look into the `ChannelInterceptor.postReceive()` implementation which is going go be called before handler. There you can check a received message for the `poison pill` symptoms and stop the consumer endpoint. Although I'm not sure how should that look when we have several producers and when one of them has sent `poison pill`, that doesn't mean that all others are exhausted as well...

Comment: Well, that was, I guess, a part of my question :D